# ORACLE - Consulta Select convertir en XML y devolver como parámetro de salida

Tags: xml, oracle

estoy trabajando en un proyecto web con varias cosas, ahora me tranque en una parte, me urge que en Oracle 10.2G, en un Store Procedure pueda hacer un select y todos los datos obtenidos por ese select los pueda retornar como parámetro de salida de dicho store procedure, entonces la pregunta clave es ¿Como convertir los resultados de un select a un XML? Sin olvidar que la versión de Oracle es la 10.2

Saludos cordiales a todos.

Answer (score 3):

Ya encontré la solucion, es algo tan simple como:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT (
      "RESULTADO",
      XMLAGG (
         XMLFOREST (cod_estado AS "cod_estado",
                    descripcion AS "descripcion")))
FROM TABLA_X
```